# Reference req : parameter estimation for hyperbolic PDEs

Tags: reference-request, parameter-estimation, inverse-problems, hyperbolic-equations

I would like to know some references (books, thesis,.. maybe recent) on "inverse problems" related to "hyperbolic PDEs" or what's commonly referred to as "Parameter estimation" in such equations.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very wide topic. Most books are either community-specific (inverse problems in geophysics, medical imaging, nondestructive testing, underwater acoustics, fluid dynamics, etc.), or generic theoretical books. As an introduction to such problems, one could suggest the [book](http://www.ipgp.fr/~tarantola/Files/Professional/Books/InverseProblemTheory.pdf) *Inverse Problem Theory 
and Methods for Model Parameter Estimation* by A. Tarantola (SIAM, Philadelphia, 2005).